# Mac not starting or going into recovery mode

Tags: imac, recovery, startup

My Mac (mid 2011 21.5" iMac running mac OS High Sierra 10.13.6) suddenly froze while watching a video and restarted. It now keeps on restarting.

Soon thereafter, my wireless keyboard stopped working, so I had to use a wired one. I tried booting into recovery and Internet recovery mode, but after the loading bar disappears it is all white. Nothing loads up.

How do I resolve this issue?
Edit: Can someone help?

Comment: Power off your iMac. Now power up and try booting into [safe mode](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201262).

Comment: @NimeshNeema The shift key is not working... and I cant seem to be able to get that command on apple site to get into safe mode

Comment: @NimeshNeema verbose mode and single user mode works and i try fsck -fy command but it doesnt work